# Error posting request to add attachment via chatter rest api. version 30.0: "Unrecognized field attachment"

Tags: rest-api, chatter, attachment

I am trying to post an attachment into the chatter feed of a bug item in GUS.
Working with api version 30.0, and using the api reference for this version at: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_binary_file.htm

I am using the URL for the specific bug, and building the request body as follows (Python):

`**result = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=attachment_headers)`

**url:**

```
https://<my GUS instance>/services/data/v30.0/chatter/feeds/record/a072g0000048yfwAAA/feed-items
```

**Headers:**

```
{'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer 00D2g0000000...ZN6tJUKiN', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data...0h3VJ7mkI', 'X-PrettyPrint': '1'}
```

**data:**

```
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
{
"body": {
"messageSegments": [
{"type": "Text", "text": "Attchment from Jira CFSL project"}], 
"attachment": [
{"attachmentType": "NewFile", "title": "image-2019-07-04-16-56-15-358.png", "description": "attachment migrated from Jira"}]
}
} 
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedItemFileUpload";
filename="image-2019-07-04-16-56-15-358.png" Content-Type: image/png 
<file content>
--F9jBDELnfBLAVmLNbnLIYibT5Icp0h3VJ7mkI--
```

Getting this error:

```
 "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR",\n  "message" : "Unrecognized field \\"attachment\
```

Tried using capabilities instead, as specified for later versions, and getting the same error for capabilities field.

Have been googling around this a lot,
would appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Sharon.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to progress with file upload.
The error on top, was that the attachment needs to be outside the body, and not be set as an array:

{
"body": {
"messageSegments": [
{"type": "Text", "text": "Attchment from Jira CFSL project"}], }
"attachment": 
{"attachmentType": "NewFile", "title": "image-2019-07-04-16-56-15-358.png", "description": "attachment migrated from Jira"}
}

The next issue: It is not written anywhere, how to write contents of a binary file into the last part, .
I was using this code:

with open(filepath, "rb") as img_file:
            my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
        image_as_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
        body_suffix+=image_as_string 
        body_suffix += "\r\n"+'--'+boundary+'--'+"\r\n";

But the png file that is being uploaded cannot be opened a png.
I assume it was not passes/interpreted correctly.
Would appreciate an example, showing how to concatenate the image content in the request,
where  appear in my original question above.

Thanks,
Sharon.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may encounter this issues,
it is not specified in the rest api docs, but the whole request needs to be sent in a binary format.
read the file in binary format, then concatenate it with the non-binary strings after applying .encode() method on these strings.

Best regards,
Sharon.